# Create Iterator from array with AMPHP

Tags: php, amphp

I have an array in php:

```
$array = [1,2,3];
```

When I do:

```
while(yield $array->advance())
```

I get `Call to a member function advance() on array`

How do I turn my array into an iterator?

Comment: You mean for/foreach?

Comment: It seems you have lots of unfinished previous questions. Are you not getting the help you need here on SO?

Comment: @Andreas yes I am, should I somehow close my questions?

Comment: And I mean: https://amphp.org/amp/iterators/

Comment: You can take the tour and learn the basics of SO, closing a question is translates to accept an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Awesome, got that figured now :) I cannot accept comments though, how can I finish a question then?

Comment: Oddly enough your profile does not show the 'informed' badge. Either way you can ask the commenter to post an answer, or post it yourself. Mind that answers need to be more than comments.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, it should now! I wasn't aware of all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `->advance()` only on instances of `Amp\Iterator`.

So you need to convert your basic php array first with the `fromIterable` method.

```
Amp\Iterator\fromIterable($array)
```